# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hypothesis'

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to run tests using pytest, but getting the following error. Any help is appreciated.

command: `pytest --nbval --cov=xxxx --cov-report html --cov-report term`

Python 3.7.4
Pandas version used: 0.25.0
Pytest version: 5.2.0

```
=========================================================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-5.2.0, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /
plugins: cov-2.8.1, nbval-0.9.4
collecting ... Fontconfig warning: ignoring C.UTF-8: not a valid language tag
collected 0 items / 1 errors
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)

================================================================================================================= ERRORS ==================================================================================================================
______________________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test session ______________________________________________________________________________________________________
root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:456: in _importconftest
    return self._conftestpath2mod[key]
E   KeyError: PosixPath('/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/conftest.py')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:462: in _importconftest
    mod = conftestpath.pyimport()
root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:701: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:142: in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/conftest.py:7: in <module>
    import hypothesis
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hypothesis'
```

Comment: Are you using conda?

Comment: not using conda, a docker container using requirements.txt file

Comment: `pip install hypothesis`

Comment: Move from root dir `/` somewhere else, e.g. `cd /tmp`, then rerun the tests and check whether the error still persists. `pytest` will try to collect and run tests from the current directory including subdirectories, so running it from root dir will collect tests from all installed packages (e.g. `pandas` here).